# Adding Condition to SUMPRODUCT Or SUMIFS Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to add a condition in SUMIFS/SUMPRODUCT formula that is `"$F$3:$F$5001<>"Pending"` but its not working any help will be appreciated.

When i remove the condition both formula works perfectly.

I do not want to add SUM for values which has Pending status in `Col"F"`

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$5000,$F$3:$F$5001<>"Pending",$E$3:$E$5000,N3)

=SUMPRODUCT(($E$3:$E$5001=N3)*($F$3:$F$5001<>"Pending")*C3:C5000))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust bracketing in `SUMPRODUCT()` and condition to `SUMIFS()` formula. Try-

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$5000,$F$3:$F$5001,"<>Pending",$E$3:$E$5000,N3)

=SUMPRODUCT(($E$3:$E$5001=N3)*($F$3:$F$5001<>"Pending")*(C3:C5000))
```